# No prompt from Biggoron to enter a secret

Tags: zelda-oracle-of-seasons

I am trying to speak with Biggoron to give him the secret to get the Biggoron sword, but for some reason I cannot get him to ask about the secret. I have done the trading sequence (and got the Noble Sword) and have completed the first five dungeons.

I have successfully entered secrets in this particular save before, so that is not the issue. Did I miss something?

Comment: Just to check - you started the game as a linked game, right? (entering a specific secret at the beginning of the game)

Comment: If you did start a linked game, you get the sword from the goron mini game. [From the zelda wikia](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Biggoron's_Sword): "In an Oracle of Seasons Linked Game, Link can learn the Elder Secret from the Red Goron in the cave below Biggoron on Goron Mountain. The secret can be relayed to the Goron Elder found at the Goron Gallery game on Rolling Ridge of the Past in Oracle of Ages. After earning enough points in a Goron Gallery game using Biggoron's Sword, Link will be rewarded with said sword, which can be taken back to Holodrum with a secret."

Comment: @Kevin But the problem is that that doesn't work. I already have the secret, the problem is that I cannot tell it to Biggoron because of the lack of a prompt to do so.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when playing a linked game, you don't enter a secret to get the sword, but instead you win at the minigame. Maybe that's why you can't enter the secret.

Comment: "In an Oracle of Ages Linked Game, Link can learn Biggoron's Secret from a lone Goron on Rolling Ridge in the Present. The secret can be relayed to Biggoron on Goron Mountain in Oracle of Seasons. Biggoron will reward Link with Biggoron's Sword, which can be taken back to Labrynna using a secret." This is what the wiki says: learn the secret in Oracle of Ages (and I have it), then take that secret to Biggoron. The game is in Oracle of *Ages*, not Seasons (which I am playing).